# Dell R710 Mem ECC Warning: Memory sensor, transition to critical from less severe

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I purchased a DELL R710 Server, and it consistently produces memory error warnings:

> "Normal","Tue Jan 18 2011
>   03:46:33","System Board SEL: Event Log
>   sensor for System Board, log cleared
>   was asserted"
>
> "Warning","Tue Jan 18 2011
>   23:43:01","Mem ECC Warning: Memory
>   sensor, transition to non-critical
>   from OK ( DIMM_B4 ) was asserted"
>
> "Critical","Tue Jan 18 2011
>   23:43:02","Mem ECC Warning: Memory
>   sensor, transition to critical from
>   less severe ( DIMM_B4 ) was asserted"

I've reseated the DIMM's and event exchanged a whole server (i.e., got a whole new one, with new DIMMs), and the errors still occur.

The DIMMs are Hynix, which are not factory default Dell DIMMs, so I suspect them.  Any advice/pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you've replaced the entire server from Dell, then it has to be your RAM - that's the only variable you haven't eliminated.

I'm surprised Dell issued you an RMA without forcing you to change the RAM in the first place.

Comment: I found this post on Dell's site:

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/p/19322172/19658162.aspx

There is a BIOS update that sounds like it's designed to solve this problem we're having  (see the "Important Information" section):

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=28&l=en&s=dfb&releaseid=R293119&SystemID=pwe_r710&servicetag=H5RS3P1&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=11809&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=9&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=437365