# Running dset on CentOS PowerEdge R710

Tags: centos, dell-poweredge

I noticed our PowerEdge R710 server running CentOS 5.4 had a glowing orange monitor, so I checked the logs in the DRAC:

`Mem ECC Warning: Memory sensor, transition to critical from less severe ( DIMM_B9 ) was asserted

Mem ECC Warning: Memory sensor, transition to non-critical from OK ( DIMM_B3 ) was asserted 
Mem ECC Warning: Memory sensor, transition to non-critical from OK ( DIMM_B9 ) was asserted`

Oh wow, two bad DIMMs. Before I call up Dell support, I know from experience they're going to expect a dset report first. I've done so successfully on Windows servers before, but this is my first Linux server with a complaint.

I uploaded delldset_v2.2.125_x64_A01.bin to my home directory and ran `sudo ./delldset_v2.2.125_x64_A01.bin --extract`. It responded `delldset_v2.2.125_x64_A01.bin: Command not found`. I dropped the extract flag and even renamed it to just delldset.bin, but the error won't go away. Unless I'm overlooking some painfully obvious syntax goof, I now believe I'm not using Linux dset properly, despite online instructions suggesting I am. What am I missing?

I observed [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/224011/dell-r710-mem-ecc-warning-memory-sensor-transition-to-critical-from-less-sever) but I'm wary of bringing down an important DB to make a huge BIOS version jump whose compatibility with CentOS 5.4 is uncertain for a potentially non-applicable problem.

**UPDATE:** mdpc nailed it. I'm facing a new error message, encountered during report generation: I receive a stack trace and the message 'NOTE: Not found one or more packages required for chassis and storage data collection.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file set to execute (i.e. x bits on)?  If it is only RW then you can't execute it and it will not be found as an executable (command) file.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. However, now I'm stuck with a new error message, encountered during report generation: I receive a stack trace and the message 'NOTE: Not found one or more packages required for chassis and storage data collection.'